# Unable to link or upload certain png images

Tags: support, images

Sometimes when I try to link to a PNG image taken by DxTory, usually in full HD, the site just tells me that the format is not supported, however, it's the same format I used for another image that linked just fine. If I try to upload the image, it uploads it, but freezes at some point, just showing the loading bar. It will just sit there, doing nothing.

I'd imagine there's some kind of size limit going on here. The images that fail seem to be few megabytes, while I'm not sure of the successful ones.

Did I just miss the part where it mentions a limit, is there nothing mentioning it or is it failing for some other reason altogether?

The image that made me make this post is [this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10221029/dx/payday2_win32_release%202013-08-31%2011-08-37-755.png).

Comment: Can you upload the file to (say) dropbox and put a link to it in your question?

Comment: @badp Sure. I tried to link it from dropbox to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce. What's weird is that the image uploading service is provided by imgur, which [accepted the image](http://imgur.com/5OGqoup.png) without breaking a sweat.

Comment: Ran it through [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) and it uploaded just fine. It's a good idea to do that anyway, since your image is about 2x the file size it needs to be. Maybe the uploader just can't handle 32-bit PNGs or something.

Comment: @lunboks Dxtory screenshots, and some work, some don't.

Comment: What browser / OS are you using? Do you happen to know what mime-type is being used for the upload? We do check the mime-type to be one of several known types, but may have missed one.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, the SO imgur service limits are to 5mb per image, 2mb for animated ones. Which fits with this image being 5.1mb

Comment: @Oded Makes sense. Would be nice if it was mentioned while including a picture.

Comment: Unfortunately, when imgur sends us error info, that's as detailed as it gets :(

Comment: @Oded I meant something along the lines "Images must be less than 5 Mb, or less than 2Mb if animated." while you're selecting the image.

Comment: This is only information we have _after_ you have uploaded an image. When we try to upload to imgur, they send a very generic error message, not detailing the actual issue.

Comment: @Oded Sad. I hope you get something sorted out with imgur in the future to get some better error reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to *embed* an image, you don't *have* to upload through the site's interface. Just link it normally (for example with Ctrl-L), then change the markdown from

```
[enter link description here][1]
```

...to:

```
![enter link description here][1]
```

This lets you embed images from arbitrary URLs. For example:

[image: enter link description here]

---

If you actually want to upload this image... then yes, this appears to be a bug with the imgur for Stack Exchange service.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, just thought I'd ask about it.